# connection to mysql server from clojure

Tags: mysql, jdbc, clojure

I'm trying to connect to a mysql database from clojure. I'm using the example code taken from:
http://corfield.org/blog/post.cfm/connecting-clojure-and-mysql but I'm getting this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 0 ms ago.
```

The mysql server is bound to 127.0.0.1:3306. Changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in :subname doesn't help. I have set the mysql server to log everything for debugging, and it doesn't even see a connection coming. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure your MySQL server is configured to accept networking connections? IIRC some server configurations only allow unix file sockets instead of network connections. You can possibly test that by running mysqlclient -h $yourhostname ....

Answer (score 0):

I can connect to the db using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1`. But this fails to connect if I change 127.0.0.1 to localhost. my.cnf contains: `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` and as I write above, changing to 127.0.0.1 in :subname doesn't help. The thing that did the trick was putting `mysqld : ALL : ALLOW` in /etc/hosts.allow. I have no idea why this is needed, especially when all the other services that contact the MySQL server work without it.

Comment: Answering my own question, it seems as the other applications connect to mysqld through unix sockets, in which case the TCP wrappers are not used since this is not a TCP/IP network connection. The jdbc driver on the other hand connects to a host:port using TCP/IP so the wrapper library restrictions apply.